# Computing expectation of random variable (with known distribution and joint density) conditional on a sum

Tags: conditional-expectation

Given two identically distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$ (need not be independent) from the same (known) distribution (and so, known $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\E(X)$ and $\E(Y)$) and joint density, $f(x,y)$ and the conditional expectation $\E(X \mid Y)$, is it possible to compute $\E( X \mid X+Y )$?

Comment: In principle, just by knowing $f(x,y)$, you implicitly know the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ including their expectations and also $\E(X \mid Y)$. So, all of the latter "extra" information is superfluous. Note that the transformation $(X,Y) \mapsto (X,X+Y)$ is one-to-one and so transformation-of-variables will give a density for $(X,X+Y)$ (which is easy to write in terms of $f$). From this, you can then easily recover a simple formula for $\E(X \mid X+Y)$. But, saying anything more explicit within the very general assumptions you've made doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the following integrals exist, I would have thought you have

$$E[X|Y=y] = \frac{\int_x xf(x,y)dx}{\int_x f(x,y)dx}$$

$$E[X|X+Y=z] = \frac{\int_x xf(x,z-x)dx}{\int_x f(x,z-x)dx}$$

Comment: (+1) For being explicit. Good answer. :)